# How do I speed up this loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop, time

I have this code that consists of five nested loops with each one with 100 iterations and it still hasn't finished after 5 hours. I am a noob to python, so I just wrote the simplest code.
Can anyone please tell how I can reduce the run time in python to at least less than 10 sec?

```
def func(c1, a2, b2, c2, a3):
    val = (((c1+c2-a2+10-a3)/2) - ((3/2)*((((c1-a2)*(c1-a2))/(c1+b2-a2)) + (((c2-a3)*(c2-a3))/(c2+10-b2-a3)))))
    print("Value of function: {}".format(val))
    return val

for c1 in np.arange(0,10,0.1):
    print("in c1 loop")
    for a2 in np.arange(0,10,0.1):
        print("in a2 loop")
        for b2 in np.arange(0,10,0.1):
            print("in b2 loop")
            for c2 in np.arange(0,10,0.1):
                print("in c2 loop")
                for a3 in np.arange(0,10,0.1):
                    print("in a3 loop")
                    iter = iter + 1
                    print("Iteration: {}".format(iter))
                    if (a2<c1 and a3<c2 and b2<c2 and a2<b2 and a3>c1):
                        print("in condition")
                        val = func(c1, a2, b2, c2, a3)
                        if val == 0:
                            count = count + 1
                            print("Success")
                            induV = [c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, val]
                            valIsZero.append(induV)
print(count)
print(valIsZero)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that loop?

Comment: solving the function=0. To get the values of c1, c2, a2, a3, and b2

Comment: There are better and tested algorithms to get the roots of a function. Take a look at Scipy for example.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Just out of curiosity how can I reduce the run time of the above algorithm without changing the method of finding the roots?

Comment: The problem are all those nested loops. What I'd do is use a different method. This one that you are using is just not usable.

Comment: Remove all print statements. Print is slow. this will fasten it up - but it is still silly. fix your identations errors - currently your code is broken.

Comment: the indentation was messed up after pasting the code, didn't change it. Will do it now.